# Installing pyproj in Anaconda python (Ubuntu)

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, pyproj

I am trying to install pyproj on a remote server running anaconda python 2.7.15 on Ubuntu 16.04. After running `conda install -c conda-forge pyproj` (first listed option at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyproj), the package installs successfully (pyproj 2.0.2). However, upon running my program I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_qc_worker.py", line 1288, in <module>
    GC.make_metadata_caches() # For percentiles check
  File "/home/ubuntu/qc-mem/qc/lib/global_class.py", line 384, in make_metadata_caches
    mercator_arr = self.proj_arr(lat_lon_arr) # project to x/y
  File "/home/ubuntu/qc-mem/qc/lib/global_class.py", line 421, in proj_arr
    inproj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS 84
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py", line 322, in __init__
    self.crs = CRS.from_user_input(projparams if projparams is not None else kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyproj/crs.py", line 224, in from_user_input
    return cls(**value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyproj/crs.py", line 146, in __init__
    super(CRS, self).__init__(projstring)
  File "pyproj/_crs.pyx", line 307, in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyproj/datadir.py", line 62, in get_data_dir
    "Valid PROJ.4 data directory not found."
pyproj.exceptions.DataDirError: Valid PROJ.4 data directory not found.Either set the path using the environmental variable PROJ_LIB or with `pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir`.
```

In my python script, I import with `from pyproj import Proj, transform`, and the relevant lines of code are:

```
inproj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS 84
outproj = Proj(init='epsg:3857') # WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
```

Apparently, pyproj is unable to find a `data` directory. Searching the directory at 
`~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyproj`, I confirmed there is no `data` directory. I have another server with an installation of pyproj on anaconda3 that does contain a `data` directory (with an `epsg` file). I copied this directory to the anaconda2 server, and declared the path using the environment variable as instructed in the traceback:

```
export PROJ_LIB=~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyproj/data
```

I still get the same error traceback.

I cannot find a `data` directory on the github repo for pyproj (https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/).

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by installing a prior version of `pyproj`. I replaced the `pyproj-2.0.2` installation with `pyproj-1.9.6`, by running `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pyproj`. (`proj4` was also downgraded from `6.0.0` to `5.2.0` as part of this install). This is the second available conda install option listed at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyproj.

As described above, I also manually copied (`scp`) an existing `data` directory from an anaconda3 install on another server, and then exported the `PROJ_LIB` environment variable with the path to the `data` directory.

Note that when running `pyproj-1.9.6` before exporting the path to `data`, the error traceback instead indicates `RuntimeError: 'no arguments in initialization list'`. This issue is well-described by other users here: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/134.

Comment: It appears that manually copying the `data` directory is not necessary. Simply installing the pyproj 1.9.6 version will work.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of pyproj 2.2.0 works for me:

```
(base) $ conda create -c conda-forge -n proj27 python=2.7 pyproj
...
  proj4              conda-forge/linux-64::proj4-6.1.0-he751ad9_2
  pyproj             conda-forge/linux-64::pyproj-2.2.0-py27hc44880f_0
...
(base) snowal@snowal-lx2:~$ conda activate proj27
(proj27) snowal@snowal-lx2:~$ python
Python 2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 28 2019, 04:00:11) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

```py
>>> from pyproj import Proj, transform
>>> inproj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS 84
>>> outproj = Proj(init='epsg:3857') # WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'2.2.0'
```